# How can I change Firebase Cloud Function region?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase Cloud Function looks like:

```
  exports.sendRequest = functions.firestore
  .document('Links/{p_id}/Accepted/{uid}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')
     return null;
    })
```

It is being deployed it to

> us-central1

How can I change its location to

> asia-east2 ?

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in [the documentation for best practices for changing a region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region):

> If you are changing the specified regions for a function that's
>   handling production traffic, you can prevent event loss by performing
>   these steps in order:
>
> 1. **Rename the function**, and change its region or regions as desired.
> 2. **Deploy the renamed function**, which results in temporarily running the same code in both sets of regions.
> 3. **Delete the previous function**.

This procedure is pretty straightforward.